# How do I use Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to learn how to use Genetic algorithm (GA) in r. So, here is my code:

```
library(genalg)

evalf <- function(x) {
      soln <- dnorm(x, mean = 16, sd = 4) 
      return(soln)
    }

iter = 100
GAmodel <- rbga.bin(size = 5, popSize = 200, iters = iter, mutationChance = 0.002, elitism = F, evalFunc = evalf)
```

return with the warning,
`There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)` as follows:

`1: In evalVals[object] = evalFunc(population[object, ]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Further, I think GA does not return the correct answer since I got as follows:

`cat(summary.rbga(GAmodel))`

return,

```
GA Settings
  Type                  = binary chromosome
  Population size       = 200
  Number of Generations = 100
  Elitism               = FALSE
  Mutation Chance       = 0.002

Search Domain
  Var 1 = [,]
  Var 0 = [,]

GA Results
  Best Solution : 0 0 1 0 1
```

If I convert the Best Solution using `binary2decimal(c(0,0,1,0,1))`, I got `5`.  However the correct answer should be `16`.

Could you please give me suggestions on how to solve this problem using GA ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem using GA you need to change evalf to:

```
evalf <- function(x) 1/dnorm(binary2decimal(x), mean = 16, sd = 4)
```

It seems that fitness function should return smaller value for data that is closer to solution.
Also fitness function should return the value - not a vector - so you need to convert chromosome by using binary2decimal.

Comment: why do you use `1/dnorm` instead of `dnorm`

Comment: The optimum is the chromosome for which the evaluation value is minimal.

Comment: As stated in the 'genalg' package manual (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/genalg/index.html): "The optimum is the chromosome for which the evaluation value is minimal". So if you looking for an answer 16 the fitness function should return the lowest value for the chromosome, encoding 16. Thats why I use inversed 'dnorm'.